# When posting entries, how do I post tags as well as the title and url?

Tags: entry, tags

I'm trying to create a post where in the entry loop I can also post tags.

```
<a href="URL">TITLE</a>
   TAGS
```

But in my current understanding there's no way to get the post's tags where I'd assume it would be something like `entry.tags`

Answer (score 2):

In the Control Panel you'd need to create a [Tag Group](https://craftcms.com/docs/tags#tag-groups) first, which would hold all of you created tags. You then need to create a [Tags field](https://craftcms.com/docs/tags-fields) where you'd select the Tag Group created above as the `source`.

Once you've done all that, you can now add it to the fields of the `entry` type in question. If you gave the Tags field the name `tags` when you create it, you could then refer to it in your template as `entry.tags`.

In you template, you'd then loop through you tags and output them like this:

```
{% for tag in entry.tags %}
    {{ tag.title }}
{% endfor %}
```